# Remove Buttons Dynamically with an Array

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, label

I have a view that has labels being dynamically added by the user. If the use would like to edit any of the labels, they press a button and all the labels get highlighted with a delete button and move button. (Editing is another bridge I’ll cross later).

My issue is: What is the best way to turn the buttons on and off? I have a method that turns the buttons on… but I am at a loss as to how I turn them off when done editing. Do I need to tag my buttons and then just ‘hide them’? Or do I just remove them all totally? How do I parse all the buttons that are turned on then, turn them off. Do I need to put them in an array as well? The labels are tagged with unique numbers so I know which label is which.

Any thoughts? Guidance? If I am doing it all wrong please tell me.

Here is a couple methods I have:

```
- (void) showEditableText {
// Parse the array of labels
    if(textArray.count > 0){
        for(UILabel *label in textArray){

//Add Delete Button           
 UIImage * delButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GUI_Delete.png"];
            UIButton * delThisButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x - delButtonImage.size.width, label.frame.origin.y - delButtonImage.size.height, delButtonImage.size.width, delButtonImage.size.height)];
 [delThisButton setBackgroundImage:delButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [delThisButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteThisLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self addSubview:delThisButton];

            //Add a move button
            UIImage * moveButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GUI_Move.png"];
            UIButton * moveThisButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width + moveButtonImage.size.width), label.frame.origin.y - moveButtonImage.size.height, moveButtonImage.size.width, moveButtonImage.size.height)];
 [moveThisButton setBackgroundImage:moveButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [moveThisButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moveThisLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self addSubview:moveThisButton];

//Make the text highlighed
            label.highlighted = YES;
            label.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:203/255.0f green:230/255.0f blue:239/255.0f alpha:1];
            label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
}


- (void) doneEditingText {
    if(textArray.count > 0){
        for(UILabel *label in textArray){
//THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK? WHAT DO I DO?

            label.highlighted = NO;
            label.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create and delete buttons as you need them, or you can hide/unhide them.  Depends mostly on whether a fixed set of them will work (hide/unhide) or whether the number (and maybe style) is dynamic (create/delete).  All buttons can be pointed to the same touch event methods (use the button @ call parm to tell them apart).  Put the button @s in an array to make it easier to sort them out.

Answer (score 2):

```
//inside your first method set the same tag to your all buttons

-(void) showEditableText {

........
.......
.......
 delThisButton.tag = 10;

 moveThisButton.tag = 10;

}

//inside your second method delete all the subviews using this tag as shown below..

-(void) doneEditingText {

    if(textArray.count > 0){
        for(UILabel *label in textArray){
..............................

//THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK? WHAT DO I DO?

    for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        if (subview.tag == 10) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
...............................

            label.highlighted = NO;
            label.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had tinkered with the tags but was at a loss as to how to parse them! Thanks!

Comment: Ah this works only if all the button tags are the same. I loose the ability to create button tags. if I assign a button a tag during creation, when I cycle through to remove them, it starts leaving some behind.

Comment: Instead of that 10 you can use a common variable.

Comment: I can create any variable I want and assign it. But the issue presents that once the buttons are unique, I can't iterate through and remove them. Example: I create 10 buttons with tags 1 - 10. Once I go to remove subview.tag == i, some get left behind and other weird things begin to happen.

Comment: Like this for example 

'int i =0;
        for (UIButton * button in [self subviews]) {
             if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                 if (button.tag == i){
                        [button removeFromSuperview];
                    } //end if
               } // end if
              i++;
        } //end for '

Answer (score 0):

Move all your buttons code to `viewDidLoad`, hide them (`button.hidden = YES`). When you start/finish editing your text, unhide and hide your buttons. You need to have an ivar to contain the buttons too. So add them in your .h file.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I have no way of know how many labels the user is going to create. Or are you talking about just the one Move and Delete button?

Comment: I was just talking about the move and delete button. I'm not sure what you meant to do with the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UIView *   seletetButton = nil;
for (UIView * btn in self.view.subviews){
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (seletetButton.tag != btn.tag)
        {
            [btn removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```